# iTunes Search API URL Encoding Bug?

Tags: url, itunes, urlencode

If I want to search for "2001: A Space Odyssey" in the iTunes API, I go to URL:
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=2001%3A+A+Space+Odyssey&media=movie&entity=movie&attribute=movieTerm
but get no results, even though the movie is there. If I search with just search term "Odyssey," I get the correct result. Am I making a mistake encoding my search term into the URL, or is this a bug in iTunes' search API?

Comment: That URL works fine for me, Dave; `"resultCount":1 ...`

Comment: Really? I'm getting `"resultCount":0`...

Comment: Try to load the URL about 10 times. Sometimes it comes up, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be intermittent